# Electron builder - publish to local artifactory, and add requestheaders for authentication

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, artifactory, electron-builder

I'm trying to understand the Docs regarding custom publishing in electron builder, i have a local artifactory server with authentication,
so what i understand so far that when using this option it will automatically upload the newly created artifact to the URL pointed
assuming using release, but i also need to be an authentic user in order to upload, i tried adding requestheaders for authentication but i get the following error
package.json

```
`
"publish": {
 "provider": "generic",
 "url": "example.com/aa/bb",
 "requestHeaders":{ "Authorization:":"Basic KEY" }
 }
`
```

as soon as i try to do this i get this error

- configuration.publish.requestHeaders has an unknown property 'Authorization'. These properties are valid: object {}

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be the same as [this issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/6635) in Electron-Builder.

As a workaround, you can try to set the basic credentials in the URL itself:

```
"publish": {
 "provider": "generic",
 "url": "myuser:mypass@example.com/aa/bb"
 }
```

(see [RFC-1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.html#section-3.1))

Comment: i got to read it, but i moved to work on another task i will mark it as an answer as soon as i go back to working on this thanks